# Expand bounding boxes in edges of images to square

Tags: python

I have a function designed to expand bounding boxes in images to squares.

```
def expand_bbox(bbox, img_shape):

    h, w = bbox[2] - bbox[0], bbox[3] - bbox[1]
    if h < w:
        d = w - h
        u = min(bbox[0], d // 2) 
        v = d - u
        bbox[0] -= u
        bbox[2] += v
    else:
        d = h - w
        u = min(bbox[1], d // 2)
        v = d - u
        bbox[1] -= u
        bbox[3] += v

    bbox[0] = max(bbox[0], 0)
    bbox[1] = max(bbox[1], 0)
    bbox[2] = min(bbox[2], img_shape[0]) 
    bbox[3] = min(bbox[3], img_shape[1])
    h, w = bbox[2] - bbox[0], bbox[3] - bbox[1]
    assert h == w
    inc = h // 2
    inc = min(inc, bbox[0])
    inc = min(inc, bbox[1])
    inc = min(inc, img_shape[0] - bbox[2])
    inc = min(inc, img_shape[1] - bbox[3])
    bbox[0] -= inc
    bbox[1] -= inc
    bbox[2] += inc
    bbox[3] += inc
    h, w = bbox[2] - bbox[0], bbox[3] - bbox[1]
    assert h == w
    return bbox
```

It works fine for cases where the bounding box appears inside the image, but fails to expand boxes in the edges of images (i.e. when the bounding box is [979, 157, 1080, 261] and the image shape is (1080, 1920, 3))

What can I do make sure that the bounding box captures bounding boxes that appear along the edges of the images?

Comment: When I try your sample input, I get an AssertionError on the first `assert`.

Comment: @ScottHunter Yes, that's expected since the assert is checking that the bound box will produce a square image before adding the increments to the sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure all this code could be prettier, but if you search for a working code, I would go for adding some ifs:

```
# if increasing the upper edge position would go outside the img_shape, do not increase it, decrease bottom instead.
if bbox[2] + v > img_shape[0]:
    bbox[0] -= u + v
else:
    bbox[0] -= u
    bbox[2] += v
```

And the same for width.